# Change code chunk highlighting in Hugo theme

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to change the syntax highlighting of code chunks in a Hugo theme ("Call me Sam"). I'm rendering the content using R's `blogdown`, so the code chunks are in `Rmarkdown`. On my `config.toml` I've got `pygmentsStyle = "monokai"` and `pygmentsCodefences = true`. Following this instructions https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup/, I've added this as well (maybe my goal is not about the markup though):

```
[markup]
  [markup.highlight]
    codeFences = true
    guessSyntax = false
    hl_Lines = ""
    lineNoStart = 1
    lineNos = false
    lineNumbersInTable = true
    noClasses = true
    style = "monokai"
    tabWidth = 4
```

I don't see any changes in the code chunks of my page. I think I need to change the `css` file as well (which one??)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code fences, try using Hugo's built-in [highlight shortcode](https://gohugo.io/content-management/syntax-highlighting/#highlight-shortcode) instead, for example:

```
{{< highlight toml >}}
[markup]
  [markup.highlight]
    codeFences = true
    guessSyntax = false
    hl_Lines = ""
    lineNoStart = 1
    lineNos = false
    lineNumbersInTable = true
    noClasses = true
    style = "monokai"
    tabWidth = 4
{{< / highlight >}}
```

I often have problems with Hugo's code-fence highlighting, but rarely have a problem with Hugo's built-in highlight shortcode. You can see an example of the results of the highlight shortcode at https://www.ii.com/ordinary-extraordinary-markdown/#this-articles-markdown-flavor after you click the "Click this" details twisty (this is my site :-)).

Comment: Where do you put this code? int the `toml` or somewhere else?

Comment: Your question makes me wonder if I understood your original question. Are you trying to highlight code chunks 1) in your writing in the `content/` directory when it appears in your published site or 2) in your text editor when you are editing any file, e.g., a template in the `layouts/` directory? If you're asking about #1, put the fragment I posted above in your content file, e.g. whatever.Rmd.[^] If you're asking about #2, you probably want to turn on "syntax highlighting" in your text editor. [^] `.Rmd` can be any [file extension Hugo knows about](https://www.ii.com/hugo-markup-languages/)

Comment: PS - I don't know if the highlight shortcode works in a `.Rmd` file so when you are experimenting with this, I recommend you first try the highlight shortcode in a `.md` file. I hope this helps you understand Hugo's syntax highlighting!

Comment: I was curious about shortcodes in `.Rmd` files so did a little bit of searching and discovered that the phrase "code chunks" has a special meaning in the R world. So now I'm quite sure that I did not understand your original question. I hope someone from the blogdown and R world can help.  --nm who knows hardly anything about blogdown and R (but I experimented with them a couple years ago when I was first learning Hugo)